# Android Methods calling tracking

Tags: java, android, compiler-construction, profiling

I was halfway of changing my code to print a Log message each time I enter and exit a method. When I thought that probably there is some feature or plugin for Eclipse that can track it for me and show me. After all, this is information the java compiler has at hand.

What I need is to see the **order** in which each method is called and returns.

It should print the method name and all the stack above it, so I can know who called.

**Optionally**, if it prints the time of enter and return and the difference, it would be good info for profiling.

I remember trying TraceView in the past, I don't know if it is the answr, but I clearly remember that there was too much information there and I could not get a clear picture of what was going on.
If someone knows how to properly use it to get only the info I need, it would be great too.

**UPDATE:**
I am having hard time using TraceView and his companion dmtracedump. I did something I wasn't supposed to do, I searched dmtracedump code source and look into it.
This is code producing the error message I am getting.

```
TraceData data1;
DataKeys* dataKeys = parseDataKeys(&data1, gOptions.traceFileName,
                                   &sumThreadTime);
if (dataKeys == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot read trace.\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

But I don't know how to fix the trace file.
  It is generated by         `Debug.startMethodTracing("tracefile");`

I wish there was a way to tell the Java compiler to print each method call. I am quite frustrated at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to modify the file by  myself to insert and delete Log messages anywhere in my source.

I wrote it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960339/android-eclipse-use-external-tools-to-run-a-script-on-the-code/10960605#10960605)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest rather than implementing your own profiling service, use [the absolutely excellent tool TraceView](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) that Google provides us with!

If you are having issues using TraceView, you can only profile certain parts of your code by using:

```
// start tracing to "/sdcard/calc.trace"
Debug.startMethodTracing("calc");
// ...
// stop tracing
Debug.stopMethodTracing();
```

I've used it myself, and it tells you just about everything you'd need to know for profiling.

Comment: Yes, I am willing to do that, see my last paragraph. When I used it I got tons of info, most of it I don't need right now. Mainly I could not use the results because of it. Do you know how to limit the amount of tracing info? :::: Also I remember that doing it with the start/stop method tracing did generate a trace file but I could not figure how to open it from inside Eclipse, I then used the StartMethodProfiling button inthe DDMS prespective.

Comment: TraceView is a seperate program that is included with the Android SDK

Comment: Yes, I know. Now you have learned you can use it from within Eclipse, from the DDMS perspective. :::: It is explained in the link you posted. But still... too much info; I don't want to see all the OS calls, which are majority, only my methods.

Comment: It's been awhile since I've used it, but you should be able to sort by name to make it easier

Comment: After struggling to make TraceView and dmtracedump work as I want I can say that "the absolutely excellent tool" is crap. :::: Poorly designed UI and no features to filter off unwanted entries. No help documentation. And that's the tool that works!, dmtracedump does not even read the trace file.