# Android Eclipse Use external tools to run a script on the code

Tags: android, regex, eclipse, perl

I found out that a solution to many of my unanswered questions was to run a perl script on the  code to perform some changes that are hard to impossible to do with regexs or musch simpler than some advices I got to hook into DalVik.

So  this is going to be a **self-answered question** were I tell you how I manage to do it, **step by step**. I hope this will help people to solve some of their problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The target is to run the following command line from within Eclipse on my currently opened file and refresh it to see the results:

perl -S -pi.bak myscript.pl

I am going to use an External Tools configuration.
this guide is based on Eclipse 3.7.1

1. Open **Run** -> **External Tools** -> **External Tools Configuration ...**
   (Alternatively you can open it from the Run icon with the small red toolbox on the corner)
2. Select **Program**
3. Add a **New Launch Configuration** (First Icon with the little plus on the top right corner or right click on Program -> **New**)
4. You should see this:
   [image: External Tools Configuration Dialog]
5. Fill the **Name**
6. On the location put the path to the tool you want to launch (in this case perl: **C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe**)
7. In the working direectory choose from the **Variables...**, **${container_loc}** which is the directory of the file currently on the IDE
8. As arguments put: **-S -pi.bak ${file_prompt:Select Perl Script:D:\marcelo\Perl\bin\myscript.pl} ${container_name}**
   Again you don't have to type ${container_name} or ${file_prompt...} you can choose it from Variables...
9. Press **Apply**
    You should see this now:
   [image]
10. Go to the **Refresh** tab and check **Refresh resources upon completion** and choose from the options **The selected resource**
11. Go to the **Build** tab and uncheck **Build before launch**

We are done, now several notes:

- In the **Common** tab you can check **External Tools** under **Add to favorites menu** and your script will appear on the External Tools submenu, without having to run it first.
- You probably noticed there are a lot of other options, feel free to experiment
- This example just modifies the file in the IDE. The contents of myscript.pl are:

> > next unless /Log.i/;
> >     s/\bint\s+(\w+)/int n_$1/g;
> >     s/\bString\s+(\w+)/String s_$1/g;

- The **${file_prompt:Select Perl Script:D:\marcelo\Perl\bin\myscript.pl}** opens a dialog box where you can select the perl script to run.
- If you want to run always the same script just replace the **${file_prompt...}** with the script name
- I installed the **EPIC plugin** on Eclipse so I can edit perl files as well
- You are not constrained to modify you resource. You can just run a script that generates outputs from the current file. The output of the script, also any errors encountered, are displayed in the **Console**
  Tip: In perl if you want to both write the new file out and also print out a message for the user, use STDERR to print out the message and STDOUT to print out the file.